# Why does FirstNode.GetType() return an XElement and not a XNode

Tags: c#, types, linq-to-xml

The c# docs says that the FirstNode property returns a XNode.

```
public System.Xml.Linq.XNode FirstNode { get; }
```

However when i call the GetType() method on it, it says `System.Xml.Linq.XElement`

For example..

```
var MyElement = new XElement("Base",
                new XElement("FirstName", "John",
                    new XComment("Thats a cool name")),
                new XElement("LastName", "Doe")
            );

Console.WriteLine(MyElement.FirstNode.GetType());//System.Xml.Linq.XElement
```

Further more, It doesnt have the methods which apply to `XElements` like the property `FirstNode` itself.
Can someone explain what is going on.

Comment: And why not an XObject?  and why not just an _object_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.GetType` returns the exact runtime type of the current instance([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?view=netcore-3.1)). And node returned by `First` in your case is `XElement`, which is descendant of `XNode`.

Type hierarchy for `XElement` from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement?view=netcore-3.1):

```
Object -> XObject -> XNode -> XContainer -> XElement
```

Comment: Thanks. Well explained

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement?view=netcore-3.1), XElement inherits from XNode. FirstNode can be anything that inherits from XNode.